# How to mask ssn input to xxx-xx-1234 in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

So I have a directive called ssnMask that looks like:

```
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    function format(value) {
      if (value && value.length === 9) {
        var mask = 'xxx-xx-' + value.substr(5);

        ngModel.$setViewValue(mask);
        ngModel.$render();
      }

      return value;
    };

    ngModel.$parsers.push(formatter);
  }
};
```

And I use it in conjunction with ui-mask on the template as so:

```
<input id="ssn"
           ng-model="ctrl.ssn"
           ssn-mask
           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
           name="ssn"
           type="text"
           ui-mask="999-99-9999"
           ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" />
```

My expected behavior is to input 9 digits and then the first 5 turn into xxx-xx on blur.  This is working exactly as expected but whenever I focus back into the field, it removes the xxx-xx and I'm left with the last 4 digits only(assuming because of the ui-mask).  Is there a way to have all 9 numbers show up on focus but get masked on blur?

Comment: How the $parsers and `ui-mask` is interacting is likely the cause - after the blur event the $viewValue is turned into the string `xxx-xx-1234`, which does not satisfy the `ui-mask` as it requires all those 'x' to be a numeral [0-9]. Do you have a plunker or fiddle available showing the issue?

Comment: Hey @NathanBeck, I tried to set up a fiddle but it doesn't seem to be working correctly for whatever reason.  Anyways, I believe you are right that the x's don't satisfy the ui-mask.  I'm not even sure what a good solution here would be for my situation now..